# How to close brackets in vim

Tags: vim

What is the line to add to my `~/.vimrc` to do the following ?:

1) If I open a `{` on line X, it automatically creates a `}` on line X+2 with correct indentation:

```
1 something foo(bar){
2 
3 }
```

2) Cursor automatically goes to line X+2 and it creates 4 white spaces (an indentation level):

```
1 something foo(bar){
2     . <-- cursor here
3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Making_Parenthesis_And_Brackets_Handling_Easier).

The following will do the job:

```
inoremap { {<CR><BS>}<Esc>ko
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set autoindent
set smartindent
```